# How do I mock an OpenSearch client for unit testing?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, ts-jest, opensearch

I have an OpenSearch domain that I would like to mock in order to unit test my function (written in TypeScript) that makes calls to it. My OpenSearch client works as expected, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to mock that client so that I can write unit tests that validate how I am handling OpenSearch responses. I wasn't able to find much documentation or examples of other folks who have solved this, so I wonder if I'm headed in the wrong direction or not following the expected pattern for testing an OpenSearch client.

The constructor for my OpenSearch client object looks like this:

```
import { Client } from '@opensearch-project/opensearch'

const opensearch = new Client({
   ...AwsSigv4Signer({
     region: "us-east-1",
     service: "es",
   }),
   node: process.env.SEARCH_DOMAIN_ENDPOINT
})
```

Here is the code I have to mock this client:

```
import { Client, Connection } from "@opensearch-project/opensearch"
import Mock from "@elastic/elasticsearch-mock"

describe('test content search handler', function () {
    it('should return list of content when no filter parameters are passed', async function() {
         const openSearchMock = new Mock();
         const opensearch = new Client({
           Connection: openSearchMock.getConnection() as any,
           node: process.env.SEARCH_DOMAIN_ENDPOINT
         });

         openSearchMock.add({
           method: "GET",
           path: "/index/_search"
         }, () => {
            return {
              status: 'ok'
            }
         })
    });
});
```

When I try to run this test, I get an error with this message:
`elasticsearch_mock_1.default is not a constructor`

For my original client I used [this OpenSearch documentation](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/javascript/index/), which was really helpful, but could n't find any OpenSearch documentation specific to how to mock an OpenSearch client. [This forum post](https://forum.opensearch.org/t/about-unit-testing-in-opensearch-js/13619) suggests it's doable, but doesn't have any guidance or example on how to set them up.

[This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71358008/mock-opensearch-client-in-jest-unit-test) has the best example I can find, but I'm not seeing the same behavior this person describes, seems like they are at least able to initialize their OpenSearch client.

Any ideas on what I'm missing to be able to successfully mock my OpenSearch client?